# Getting unexpected multi-threading behaviour

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to using threading to get the list of prime numbers. However when I run the program I get redundant prime numbers in the result.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var r2 = DoThread();
                Array.Sort(r2);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { }
        }

public static int[] DoThread()
        {
            var task = new List<MyThread>(){
                new MyThread(){start = 3, end = 25000},
                new MyThread(){start = 25001, end = 50000},
                new MyThread(){start = 50001, end = 75000},
                new MyThread(){start = 75001, end = 100000-3}
            };
            var threads = new List<Thread>()
            {
                new Thread(task[0].MyDelegate),
                new Thread(task[1].MyDelegate),
                new Thread(task[2].MyDelegate),
                new Thread(task[3].MyDelegate)
            };

            threads.ForEach(t => { t.Start(); });
            threads.ForEach(t => { t.Join(); });

            var res = new List<int>();
            task.ForEach(t => res.AddRange(t.result));
            return res.ToArray();
        }

public class MyThread
    {
        public int[] result;
        public int start;
        public int end;

        public void MyDelegate()
        {
            IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(start, end);
            var parallelQuery =
              from n in numbers
              where Enumerable.Range(2, (int)Math.Sqrt(n)).All(i => n % i > 0)
              select n;
            result = parallelQuery.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `redundant prime number`?

Comment: Do you mean DUPLICATE prime numbers?

Comment: I get same prime numbers, like say 11, twice in the final result array after merging all four as .,,,11,11,13,17,19,19,23...

Comment: Yes duplicate prime numbers.

Comment: I want to use data parallelism myself. In MyDelegate I have not used PLINQ.

Comment: Well, I tried your code and it seemed to work fine. No duplicates that I could see.

Comment: @IsaacMcGarvey: How many prime numbers did you get in result? I get 22516 prime numbers having duplicates.

Comment: The length of r2 is 22516 for me.

Comment: It should not be 22516. Because There are only 9592 prime numbers below 100,000.

Comment: Ah, the duplicates only start after 50,000. I didn't look that high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enumerable.Range(start, end)` does not take a start-end pair. It takes `start` and `count`.

You would have found this bug yourself by using the debugger and inspecting runtime state. Just looking at buggy code often does not lead to finding it. Investigation is needed.

Apart from that your code is thread-safe although by far more complicated than it would have been using something like PLINQ:

```
var res = tasks.AsParallel().SelectMany(t => t.GetPrimes()).ToList();
```

Work on a higher level. Don't manage threads.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I had just copied and used first time :D

Comment: Doesn't matter where the code came from. It is an important skill to be able to fix any piece of code by investigating. You often have to fix other peoples stuff. Glad your problem is solved, though.